# ssh "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I can still ssh into my aws ec2-instance yesterday, but today get

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

with command

```
ssh -i "keypair_ireland.pem" ubuntu@instance-ip
```

The reason for that is I seems to have altered the chmod of /home/ubuntu directory, aka. /home/ubuntu/.ssh  on the EBS volumne(root device), so that ssh is not effective anymore.

now I can not ssh into the instance

how could I then change it back ? Is there any other way I can log into the remote server?

update ============================================================

I have done the following things to try to fix it

```
1. identify a running instance I can log in
2. stop this instance (because volumne can only attach to stopped instance)
3. attach my volumn to instance in step 1 at point /dev/sdf (not the root device), it shows in the list of block device, not root device
4. start instance in step 1
5. instance in step 1 can not be ssh into anymore
```

update ===========================================

security group of my instance

> 22    tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔

update =============================================

volume I used from a snapshot of a AWS Marketplace AMI

error I got when I try to attach volume to the running instance

> Error attaching volume: Cannot attach volume 'vol-6dc7aa2' with
>   Marketplace codes as the instance 'i-932391e' is not in the 'stopped'
>   state.

Comment: Did you check if SSH from your computer is allowed in the Security Group of these instances?

Comment: yes. it is allowed ssh 0.0.0.0

Comment: What if you ssh into the running instance and only after that you attach the volume?

Comment: @brunodea  aws doesn't allow attach volume to a running instance

Comment: @brunodea  because the volume I used from a snapshot of a AWS Marketplace AMI

Answer (score 0):

In your place, I would probably do something like the following:

1. Stop the instance;
2. Detach the EBS volume;
3. Attach it to a running instance;
4. Fix the /home/ubuntu permissions. If you don't know what the permissions should be, you could use the same as in /home/user of the running instance;
5. Detach the volume from the running instance;
6. Reattach to the stopped instance;
7. Start the instance and try to ssh it again.

Comment: thanks for your idea, I have tried and got another problem included in my update